# Chrome Extension - Clear form text OnClick

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Having issues with the below code with when my Input is clicked i need it to clear the current text.

The code currently works just as plain HTML/Javascript however when loaded into the Chrome Extension is when it seems to not work.

```
<input type="text" name="enter" onfocus="this.value=''" size="4" class="enter" value="17710" id="text_input" />
```

Currently when the input is click the previous text is still in there. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When I click the textbox, text is cleared.  Previous javascript code breaking?

Comment: Weird.. seems to work fine [link](http://jsfiddle.net/4uECD/)

Comment: The Code works normal as just plain HTML and Javascipt, Its only inside a Chrome Extension the code seems unuseable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline JavaScript will not be executed in a Chrome extension for security purposes.

[See the documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#JSExecution) for details on how to work around that.

Extract:

> The clickHandler definition needs to move into an external JavaScript file (popup.js would be a good target).
>
> The inline event handler definitions must be rewritten in terms of addEventListener and extracted into popup.js.

In your case, that means that your function for `onfocus` needs to be in a separate script file and you need to hook it up to your input with `addEventListener`.

Comment: Put my code in js file and added click handler as you suggested. thank you